# How to put image on right center corner of StatusStrip

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a StatusStrip with 2 controls: ToolStripProgressBar and ToolStripStatusLabel, placed on left side of StatusStrip, now i want to put logo image on right corner of my statusStrip, how can i do that ?

What I could do is to import my image with BackGroundImage property and then I set BackgroundImageLayout property to zoom but this just center and zoom my image logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place **two more** `ToolStripStatusLabels` on the `StatusStrip`!

- The first one should have `Text = "";` and `Spring = true:`
- The second one should have your logo `Image` set and an `Display = Image` style.

Controls with `Spring = true` together use up all the available spec; so here the first, empty  `ToolStripStatusLabels` will push the second one with the `Image` to the right..